# Error install jspm for ubuntu

Tags: jspm

I'm a begginer with jspm. 
First I ran "npm install jspm -g", it was ok.
After that I ran

```
    cd my-project
    npm install jspm --save-dev
```

it appeared error.

```
    npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-45-generic
    npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "jspm" "--save-dev"
    npm ERR! node v6.8.1
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
    npm ERR! code ENOSELF

    npm ERR! Refusing to install jspm as a dependency of itself
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
    npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /var/www/html/learning/angular2/jspm-demo/npm-debug.log
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Guess #1: Is `jspm` the value for `name` property in your `package.json`? If so, rename it to something else.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: {
         "name": "jspm",
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "description": "",
          "main": "index.js",
         "scripts": {
           "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
         },
         "keywords": [],
         "author": "",
         "license": "ISC"
      }
This is my package.json

Comment: You can't add a dependency with the same name as your package - http://thisdavej.com/node-newbie-error-npm-refusing-to-install-package-as-a-dependency-of-itself/

Comment: I changed the value of "name" in package.json and it worked fine.
Thanks you very much :D